# Can hydrogen have 3 electrons?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms, ions

Can i in any way force a hydrogen atom to have three electrons? Two electrons in first shell and one in the second?

Answer (score 4):

The double hydrogen anion H$^{--}$ does not exist as a stable species.  (It occurs as a resonance, with a lifetime of 23 ns though.)  If you tried to add another electron to a H$^{-}$ ion, the repulsion from the two core 1$s$ electrons would be greater than the attraction due to the nucleus. The result is that there is no bound 2$s$ energy level.

In fact, there is not even a bound $1s^{1}2s^{1}$ state of H$^{-}$.  Even with only two electrons total, there is not a bound 2$s$ orbital.

Comment: I’m not sure there are any doubly negative ions that is stable.